# USB-to-Serial cable based on the Prolific chip - Windows 7 driver problem

Tags: usb, serial

I have a problem getting a USB-to-Serial cable based on the Prolific PL-2303 chip working under Windows 7. This problem has drained me for a few hours and after searching for miles on the Internet I have been unable to find the correct solution. The Prolific PL-2303 chip is used extensively for serial to USB connectivity.

It seems others also have a problem getting cables based on this chip working under Windows 7 after downloading various drivers. How can I get my PL-2303 based device working under Windows 7?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting in this manner. I am not sure if I am allowed to do this. If not, please remove it and I will not make such posts again (but tell me so that I know). I was under the (perhaps misinterpreted) impression that we are trying to build a community contributed knowledge-base here.

Comment: there should be a checkbox left bottom to your edit box.
Hit edit and mark it "community wiki"

Comment: @capcom You probably should have used the answer your own question option and wrote the question and answer separately instead of this way. Also this is a known problem with pirated Prolific chips.

Comment: Recent Prolific PL2303 drivers work without problems on W7/32 and W7/64. We have them on many thousand machines at work, and I have at lease 20 devices with PL2303 on board working on my W7/64 machines at home, with those drivers. Problem arises when devices with embedded PL2303 have custom drivers and with "unofficial" Prolific hardware...

Comment: @Axeman Yes, and I believe I am a victim of the fake hardware. So the official drivers didn't work for me, even the latest one. This is the only workaround I found. I purchased my serial to USB adapters from eBay, so I'm not surprised.

Comment: There's no reason to make it community wiki. What you should do is to create an answer below with the actual answer, and edit the question accordingly. I can do it for you, but then I would get the rep for the answer, it's better if you do it yourself :)

Comment: The cause of this problem (usually) is counterfeit Prolific (and FTDI) chips. The latest driver versions that Win'Update installs recognizes the bogus chips and disables the interface. Rolling back the driver will bypass the problem by using an older revision that does not activate the kill-switch. The Baofeng (ham radio) programming cables are a classic example, a Google search for them will provide more info.

Comment: This question maybe fit for superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

### Original answer from capcom:

I found a very simple solution which I did not find listed anywhere, which is why I am outlining it here to help anyone else who may run into a similar problem in the future. I am running a Win7 64 bit machine.

1. Open Device Manager
2. Navigate to your device (it should have a yellow exclamation mark on it)
3. Right click on it, and choose *update driver*.
4. Click *Browse my Computer...*
5. Click *Let me pick from a list...*
6. A list of all of the drivers should show. Choose the oldest Prolific driver on the list. I chose version 3.2.0 from 2007
7. Install it, and you're done!

If you are using PuTTy, note that when you connect, the COM port may not work as expected. What you should do, if you need to, is go into the Serial options in the main PuTTy window, and turn off flow control.

Everything should work right now.

Comment: But isn't this off-topic?